# Using javascript to set the height of a iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I want to set the css height of an iframe based on how big the screens is but I don't know how to do this.

CSS:

```
#iframeplate{
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body onload="setGround()">
  <iframe id="iframeplate" class="idIframe"  frameborder=0 border=0   width="100%"  scrolling-y="no"  src="#">
  </iframe>
</body>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function setGround() { 
  var groundElement = document.getElementById('iframeplate'); 
  groundElement.style.height = getWindowHeight() + 'px'; 
} 
}

</script>
```

Can anyone see why this would not work? Or any ideas on a better way to do it?

Comment: Did you look at any of the similar questions on the right?

Comment: You have one extra "}" in your JS code. Does your function "getWindowHeight()" return something at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is the method of `getWindowHeight`,there isn't output.

Try this:

```
groundElement.style.height = window.screen.availHeight + 'px';
```

Comment: yeah right on getWindowHeight had no output window.innerHeight did the job thank you put me on the right line of thinking thanks

Answer (score 1):

Syntax error. Try this:

```
<iframe id="iframeplate" class="idIframe" frameborder=0 border=0 width="100%" scrolling-y="no" src="#"></iframe>


<script type="text/javascript">
function setGround() { 
    var groundElement = document.getElementById('iframeplate'); 
    groundElement.style.height = getWindowHeight() + 'px'; 
}
</script>
```

Comment: was not it but you where right thanks did not see that there :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try it

```
<body onload="setGround()">
<iframe id="iframeplate" class="idIframe"  frameborder=0 border=0   width="100%"  scrolling-y="no"  src="#"
    </iframe>
```

Use JQuery like

```
$("iframe[id='iframeplate']").height(getWindowHeight());
```